# Grid view in C#

Tags: c#

I have problem when using session in grid view , I do not know how can i make the session dynamic not static like now .

I want to represent the search engines by session "UsserName" depend on each user that login in website.

```
<asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="3" Name="User_Id2"     SessionField="UsserName" Type="Int32" />
```

here in this statement The problem is appear when each user login to view his search engine will  see  the search engine for User number 3(that in default value) not his search engine.

so how i make the grad-view retrieve the data for the user in Session without making default value to a particle user.

i need your help as soon as possible.

Comment: you can set `DefaultValue` dynamic by setting its value from a hidden field, that will be populated on page load.

`DefaultValue=<%#HF_UserNumber.Value.ToString() %>`

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have a session field UsserName.

Also, keep a default such as -1 or so, which is not possible through your system & handle it in your stored procedure to display blank data.